# Accessing OS environment variables within a Jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is this possible? I'm trying to access the linux env variable `M2_REPO` inside my Jenkinsfile using the Jenkins pipeline plugin, however it's constantly empty.  I can run it on my bash shell just fine:

```
root@host-VirtualBox:~#  echo $M2_REPO
/media/sf_apache-maven-repository
```

But running the command in a Jenkinsfile doesn't print anything:

```
sh 'echo $M2_REPO'
```

Does the Jenkinsfile have access to OS env variables?

Answer (score 1):

When I set the variable using the [Environment Inject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) in jenkins it worked..